# Rails 3/Devise - Change Error Message for Password Reset

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am working with a Rails 3 App and am needing to adjust the error message on the password resent view. If a user types in an email address and submits it, currently, the app will display this error message:

```
Email not found
```

I am needing to change this error message to this:

```
We don't have an account with that e-mail address. Maybe you used another address?
```

I know that you can adjust this in the Devise YML file, but am not sure how to do this... any suggestions?

**Working Code**

```
class PasswordsController < Devise::PasswordsController
  def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:user][:email])

    if user.nil?
      flash.now[:notice] = "We don't have an account with that e-mail address. Maybe you used another address?"
    end

    super
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using a before_filter that checks if the email exists in the datbase and if not the it redirects you to the password reset form with a flash notice

Comment: thanks for your suggestion! I added in the working code above